# VueJS 2 component prop inconsistency when using expressions

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling a bit passing down a piece of information into one of my components.

I am trying to iterate over a list of data and pass in a boolean set to true for the last item of the list.  I am running into an interesting inconsistency where if I use `v-bind:isLast="index + 1 == tiers.length"` in the following code it evaluates to false but if I do `v-bind:test="{index: index, tiersLength: tiers.length, bool: index + 1 == tiers.length}"` and use an object to store that information rather than expecting a boolean, the bool key has a value of true within the object.

Does anyone know why this is?  And also, would this be better as a computed property?  I don’t really want to pass down more information from the tiers list into the component as I feel like that component should be oblivious to the tiers list altogether.

```
<section id="classification-metadata-editor">
  <metadata-button-row
    v-for="(row,index) in tiers"
    v-bind:row="row"
    v-bind:index="index"
    v-bind:isLast="index + 1 == tiers.length"
    v-bind:test="{index: index, tiersLength: tiers.length, bool: index + 1 == tiers.length}">
  </metadata-button-row>
</section>

isLast: false
test: {index: 0, tiersLength: 1, bool: true}
```

I'm not quite sure if this is intended as I feel I am doing a bit more than what might be intended with setting the prop but I'm not quite sure how else to do it.  I've been looking for similar questions but not quite sure of proper terminology for searches so my apologies if this is covered elsewhere.

Thank you!

Comment: Well..  After many hours of fun troubleshooting this, it looks like calling the variable isLast was actually the issue.  Changing that variable call to testing in both the bind and component, the boolean started to evaluate to true as expected.  Interesting.

It seems that capital letters are throwing off my code.  Not sure why.  Same code but replacing the variable name with isLast, lastInArray, arrayLast all came back as false but naming it testing, is_last, last_in_array, all evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign a object to prop like this:

```
v-bind:test="{index: index, tiersLength: tiers.length, bool: index + 1 == tiers.length}">
```

You have to create a computed property or method to get this object like following:

```
methods: {
  getObject (index) {
  return {index: index, tiersLength: this.tiers.length, bool: index + 1 == this.tiers.length}
  }
}
```

and use this method in template:

```
v-bind:test="getObject(index)"
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the suggestion but it still seems to be returning false where I am expecting true.

Here are the updates:

`v-bind:isLast="isLast(index)"`

Added to the parent:

`methods: {     isLast: function(index) {
  return Boolean(index + 1 === this.tiers.length)
}`

I also tried it without the Boolean..  still false.

I am also not quite sure what you mean by you cannot bind an object like that.  I did accomplish it with the above code.  Maybe that practice is not advisable?  Or non reactive so we don't use it?  Further explanation would be welcome

Comment: I figured out what was going on with my code.  Thank you so much for the assist and suggestion on organizing my code better @Saurabh.  Marking your response as the answer for the additional information given.  :)